# How can I tell HR I want to study an MBA and ask for financial help

Tags: software-industry, career-development, human-resources, applications, training

My work offers study assistance (pays partially for the degree & gives you extra leave) to undertake further education. However, my position is currently a data analyst (I have a degree in computer science). I have accepted an offer to do an MBA. I spoke to my boss about it, and he was happy to sign off on the study assistance application to HR. HR are ultimately the people who accept or deny the request.

However, part of the application is to **state why is your study is relevant to your position, team or company**. I've never had any experience in leadership but want to go down that path rather than a data analyst path. Due to me being the most tech savvy and only one who knows how to code, a lot of the techy questions and projects come to me. I usually end up being a 1 man team on the project.

I'm not sure what to say to allow HR to approve my request. I would love some help answering the question, why is your study is relevant to your position, team or company.

Comment: I think most tech companies won't have any problem paying for the cost of an MBA for an engineer as they can see that an MBA may improve the team management skills of an engineer.

Comment: Unless your company isn't a business, then this should be an easy sell.  If HR's role is to loimit company outlay, you may need to fight it, but HR is usually about providing you the benefits the company promises.

Answer (score 1):

That should be pretty easy

1. Your boss has already signed off. Maybe they are just trying to be nice, but chances are they already see a benefit. Discuss with them
2. You are a data analyst. Chances are some or all of the data you are crunching is business data. The more you understand how business works the better and more useful the analysis will be.
3. A business background will enable you to come with new methods and analyses that no one is currently asking for since they don't know what's technical possible.
4. It's logical growth step in your career.
5. Technical and business knowledge is a valuable combination.

Some of this should stick

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple, you want to broaden your skillset and experience so that you'll have a better professional overview of your work and grow with the company.